# Elasticsearch clustering behind UFW firewall

Tags: elasticsearch, firewall, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I have an Elasticsearch cluster running on two different Digital Ocean droplets. They are both set up for private networking, an I have a Mongo DB replica set running just fine with UFW rules set up to only accept connections on the relevant ports from the droplets' specific (private) IP addresses.

However I am not able to get a green Elasticsearch cluster health using the same method, only yellow. This means that the nodes are not able to connect to each other.

In elasaticsearch.yml (on both machines) I have disabled multicast and am using unicast to connect to the droplet's internal IP addresses. When I set up the firewall to accept all connections on port 9300 (ufw allow 9300) this works just fine, and the cluster health is reported as green. However, when I restrict the rule to allow only from the actual IP addresses, just as with the Mongo DB replica set, it doesn't work. I have tried with both the public and private addresses, and with IPv4 and IPv6.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPV6 is preferred by default. You can change this behavior by setting [java.net.preferIPv4Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/ipv6_guide/#ipv6-related) system property to `true`.
Also you have to see, by default ES bind to `anyLocalAddress` (typically `0.0.0.0` or `::0`). You can change this by setting `network.bind_host` with the correct ip address.

[Reference [1.3] » Modules » Network Settings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html)

---

**Update:**

First, I recommend you disable the ipv6 in your SO, you can do this following these steps:

In `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

To disable in the running system:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/disable_ipv6
```

or

```
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```

After that, you must change in `elasticsearch.yml` the value of `network.bind_host` in both nodes with their respective IP's

```
# Elasticsearch, by default, binds itself to the 0.0.0.0 address, and listens
# on port [9200-9300] for HTTP traffic and on port [9300-9400] for node-to-node
# communication. (the range means that if the port is busy, it will automatically
# try the next port).
# Set the bind address specifically (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.bind_host: 10.0.0.1
# Set the address other nodes will use to communicate with this node. If not
# set, it is automatically derived. It must point to an actual IP address.
#
network.publish_host: 10.0.0.1
```

Or set

```
# Set both 'bind_host' and 'publish_host':
#
network.host: 10.0.0.1
```

Finally you must validate the configuration of your network adapters, both must be configured correctly with IP that you used before.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! By using netstat I see that elasticsearch communicates over IPv6. I don't really understand what would be the correct IP address for ES to bind to. As of now I set network.host = [localhost, 10.0.0.1 (example)] on the first node and [localhost, 10.0.0.2 (example)] on the second host. Is this correct?

From netstat I also see that ES uses a whole range of other ports than 9300 as well, but this doesn't explain why the clusters can communicate when I open port 9300 for any traffic but not when I specify the node's IP addresses.

Comment: I got it to work now. I followed your instructions, and actually I had to allow both the internal and external IPs in the firewall to make it go through. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

if you checkout the document below it says that ES transport uses ports 9300-9400 by default.  I would try opening up that range and then seeing if you can lock it down further.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I believe the problem has something to do with unicast, as it works by only allowing port 9300 (ES automatically connects to the first one anyway, only the othes if it doesn't work) from all IPs. But I believe I overcame the problem by hardcoding the allowed IPS in elasticsearch.yml like this: discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["node1: 9200], "node2:9200"]