# Elasticsearch Access Log

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to track down who is issuing queries to an ElasticSearch Cluster.  Elastic doesn't appear to have an access log.

Is there a place where I can find out which IP is hitting the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't provide any security out of the box, and that is **on purpose and by design**.

So you have a couple solutions out there:

1. Don't let your ES cluster exposed to the open world, but put it [behind a firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127388/elasticsearch-clustering-behind-ufw-firewall) (i.e. whitelist the hosts that can access ports 9200/9300 on your nodes)
2. Look into the [Shield plugin](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield) for Elasticsearch in order to secure your environment.
3. Put an [nginx server](http://brudtkuhl.com/securing-elasticsearch) in front of your cluster to act as a reverse proxy.
4. Add simple basic authentication with either the [elasticsearch-jetty plugin](https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty) or simply the [elasticsearch-http-basic plugin](https://github.com/Asquera/elasticsearch-http-basic), which also allowws you to whitelist the client IPs that are allowed to access your cluster.

If you want to have access logs, you need either 2 or 3, but all solutions above will allow you to secure your ES environment.

Comment: Also check out this article explaining how to monitor search queries using Packetbeat: https://www.elastic.co/blog/monitoring-the-search-queries