# How can I get statistics about what clients search for when querying Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, statistics

I'm using Elasticsearch to drive a "search website" feature. I'd like to collect statistics about what people search for (and which search queries are popular).

Elasticsearch is currently running behind Nginx, so I could extract this information from the Nginx access logs - but maybe Elasticsearch can be made to track this iinformation itself?

I found the [Index stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) but that seems to be more abstract. It can be used to determne the average time needed to answer a query and such things, but it does not keep track of individual queries.

Comment: As for me it is better to put nginx logs in elasticsearch and use ES for analysis. You can get some information for sure. But you will never know, for example, what queries are popular at evening time. Many other questions can be answered only if you have additional data like your nignx.

Comment: maybe you can use showlog with very low threshold to log the queries, or you can write your own http handler plugin that audit the requests. I think ES currently uses sync logging which means writing frequently to disk may block the actual requests.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar configuration (ES behind nginx), and I up to now I always just checked nginx' logfiles directly. However, thinking about your question, **it makes much  sense to route the nginx log files through the Elastic stack to Elastic Search using logstash**, this seems to be the cleanest way.

Apparently *in deprecated version* there were some [security auditing options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/auditing.html) using a plugin termed *Shield* or *Security*, but as I said, configuring logstash to ingest nginx logfiles directly seems most endurable way for your purposes.

#### Further reading and detailed instructions

- [discuss.elastic.co: How to get elaticsearch access logs](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-get-elaticsearch-access-logs/72024)
- https://sysadmins.co.za/how-to-ingest-nginx-access-logs-to-elasticsearch-using-filebeat-and-logstash/
- [Elasticsearch Access Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916779/elasticsearch-access-log)
- [how to enable ElasticSearch http access log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730815/how-to-enable-elasticsearch-http-access-log)